# Visualize overlapping and non-overlapping ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm working on some flattening of overlapping ranges and would like to visualize the initial data (overlapping) and the resulting set (flattened) the following way:

**Initial data:**
[image]

**Resulting set:**
[image]

Is such possible with R and, for example, ggplot2?

Answer (score 2):

```
read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", text="color,start,end
red,12.5,13.8
blue,0.0,5.4
green,2.0,12.0
yellow,3.5,6.7
orange,6.7,10.0", stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> df

library(ggplot2)

df$color <- factor(df$color, levels=rev(df$color))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=start, xend=end, y=color, yend=color, color=color), size=10) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin=margin(30,30,30,30))
```

[image]

There are other posts on SO that show how to get the y labels like you have shown (we can't do *all* the work for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the second part of the question can be using @hrbrmstr 's great answer for the first part. We can use overplotting to our advantage and simply set the y coordinates for the segments to a fixed value (for example `1`, which where "red" is):

```
p <- ggplot(df) + 
     geom_segment(aes(x=start, xend=end, color=color),
                  y=1, yend=1, size=10) +
     scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + scale_color_identity() + 
     labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
     theme_minimal() +theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
     theme(axis.text.x=element_blank()) +
     theme(plot.margin=margin(30,30,30,30))
print(p)
```